# On setState object is not calling constructor it collecting data from previous object

Tags: dart, flutter

Here *postdated*,*overdue*,*cancelled* and *upcoming* are object(StatefulWidget) of class Report but
when i call setstate and change *selected* value it is not reflecting it showing
first open object only 
For example i set *selected* =0 and it show *postdated* data after that  i set *selected* = 1 it is not showing *upcoming*  and it is still showing *postdated* and not *upcoming* object 
How to solve this?

```
body: WillPopScope(
          onWillPop: onWillPop,
          child: (selected == -1
                      ? Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: 800,
                            child: DashBoard(this.callback),
                          ),
                        )
                      : selected == 0
                          ? postdated
                          : selected == 1
                              ? upcoming
                              : selected == 2
                                  ? overdue
                                  : selected == 3
                                      ? cleared
                                      : selected == 4
                                          ? cancelled
                                          : Center(
                                              child: Text("404"),
                                            ))
                        )
```

Comment: Please, show where you call setState and where you get this `selected` variable.

Comment: Also, remember that setState is asynchronous...